# Minimal degree of the morphism from a curve to $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

We do all the things in an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$. Let $C$ be a projective curve over $k$. We have been familiar with the notion "gonality", which is the minimal degree of a morphism from $C$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$. I'm curious about what we know about the minimal degree of a morphism $C\to\mathbb{P}^n$, for which in particular, I'm curious about whether the interested minimum for $C\to\mathbb{P}^n$ is exactly $\mathrm{gon}(C)+n-1$. It is obvious for rational curves and elliptic curves, but are there any results for general cases?

Well, this is trivially false for $n$ at least $2g-1$, in which case the dimension is uniquely determined by the degree. Are there any non-trivial counter-examples, in the sense that the term $h^0(K-D)$ in Riemann-Roch does not vanish?

Comment: What do you mean with "degree" for a morphism between varieties of different dimension?

Comment: @Wojowu The morphism $C\to\mathbb{P}^n$ determines a divisor on $C$, whose dimension is what I mean.

Comment: I suppose you mean the *degree* of this divisor (I don't know what is the dimension of a divisor).

Comment: If I understand correctly the question, the answer is obviously yes. You have a 
 base-point free linear system $\lvert D\rvert$ on $C$ of (projective) dimension $n$ and degree $d$; for general points $p_1,\ldots ,p_{n-1}$ in $C$, the linear system $\lvert D-p_1-\ldots -p_{n-1}\rvert$ has dimension 1 and degree $d-(n-1)$, hence $\operatorname{gon}(C)\leq d- (n-1)$ and $d\geq \operatorname{gon}(C)+n-1$, which is then the minimum possible.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question. Every smooth curve embeds in $\mathbb{P}^3$, so the only non-trivial cases are $n=1, \, 2$.

Comment: @abx Yes. What I want to say is the degree of the divisor. Can you explain why the linear system $|D-p_1-...-p_{n-1}|$ has dimension $1$?

Comment: When you subtract a general point from a linear system, the dimension drops down by 1.

Comment: I think what you want is discussed in detail in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.01359.pdf